# C# Reusable code/library for postal/zip code lookup

Tags: c#

Does anyone know of a good piece of code that can deal with Zip code lookups where a user enters a zip code to look for a service provider in an area, and if none are found you can expand the search to all zip/postal codes within X radius of the original zip/postal code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of web services out that that you may reference from c#. I suggest you enter "free zip code lookup webservice" into your favorite search engine. One example is: http://www.zipcodedepot.com/free_zipcode_soap.html

Comment: Thanks, I also found www.zipcodedownload.com, which looks appealing.